# Iterate calculation in query through each timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=9b2b6549fc2cd4321cf7bce85e6759ad)**

```
CREATE TABLE inventory (
    timestamp_inventory DATE,
    last_inbound_date DATE,
    product VARCHAR(255),
    value VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO inventory
(timestamp_inventory, last_inbound_date, product, value)
VALUES 
("2020-01-28", "2020-01-28", "Product_A", "400"),
("2020-01-29", "2020-01-28", "Product_A", "400"),
("2020-01-30", "2020-01-28", "Product_A", "400"),

("2020-01-31", "2020-01-28", "Product_A", "400"),
("2020-01-31", "2020-01-31", "Product_B", "300"),

("2020-02-01", "2020-01-28", "Product_A", "400"),
("2020-02-01", "2020-01-31", "Product_B", "300"),

("2020-02-02", "2020-01-28", "Product_A", "400"),
("2020-02-02", "2020-02-02", "Product_B", "900"),

("2020-02-03", "2020-02-03", "Product_A", "500"),
("2020-02-03", "2020-02-02", "Product_B", "900"),

("2020-02-04", "2020-02-03", "Product_A", "500"),
("2020-02-04", "2020-02-02", "Product_B", "900");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
timestamp_inventory  |  inventory_evaluation_value
---------------------|-------------------------------------
2020-01-28           |           160
2020-01-29           |           160      
2020-01-30           |           320 
2020-01-31           |           440
2020-02-01           |           520
2020-02-02           |           760
2020-02-03           |           560
2020-02-04           |           920
```

---

In the table each day the `value` per `product` in the `inventory` is inserted. 
Additionally, the `last_inbound_date` is assigned to each `product`.

Currently, I am running the below query in order to get the `inventory_evaluation_value` as you can see in the expected results:

```
SET
@query_date = '2020-02-04';

SELECT
*,
(t2.value * t2.evaluation_rate) AS inventory_evaluation_value
FROM

  (SELECT
  *,
  (CASE WHEN t1.days_in_inventory < 2 THEN 0.4
        WHEN t1.days_in_inventory < 4 THEN 0.8
        ELSE 1 END) AS evaluation_rate
    
     FROM
     
       (SELECT
       product,
       timestamp_inventory,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, last_inbound_date, @query_date) AS days_in_inventory,
       value
       FROM inventory
       WHERE timestamp_inventory = @query_date 
       GROUP BY 1) t1
 
   GROUP BY 1) t2

GROUP BY 1;
```

The query checks - based on the `@query_date` - how long a product has been in the `inventory` and then applies an `evaluation_rate` to the value of each product.

All this works fine.

---

The issue is now that I have to run this query for each `timestamp_inventory` manually because it has to calculate the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` separately for each `timestamp_inventory`.

Therefore, I am wondering if there is way to let this query **iterate** through the table in order to get the expected result in one procedure?

Comment: 'All this works fine.'- query does not produce published result.

Comment: It runs fine if you do it for each timestamp_inventory manually, However, I wan to be able to run multiple tiemstamps in one query.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT
timestamp_inventory,
SUM(t2.value * t2.evaluation_rate) AS inventory_evaluation_value
FROM

  (SELECT
  *,
  (CASE WHEN t1.days_in_inventory < 2 THEN 0.4
        WHEN t1.days_in_inventory < 4 THEN 0.8
        ELSE 1 END) AS evaluation_rate
    
     FROM
     
       (SELECT
       inventory.product,
       inventory.timestamp_inventory,
       query_date.query_date,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, inventory.last_inbound_date, query_date.query_date) AS days_in_inventory,
       inventory.value
       FROM inventory
       JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT timestamp_inventory query_date
             FROM inventory) query_date ON inventory.timestamp_inventory = query_date.query_date 
       GROUP BY inventory.product, query_date.query_date) t1
 
   GROUP BY 1,3) t2

GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8e418413df362d73106d24bd30a24b44) (with some comments).

Answer (score 0):

Your query is malformed . . . because of all the `GROUP BY`s.  Happily, they are not necessary.  So, I would recommend:

```
SELECT i.*, (i.value * i.evaluation_rate) AS inventory_evaluation_value
FROM (SELECT i.product, i.timestamp_inventory, i.value,
             (CASE WHEN i.days_in_inventory < 2 THEN 0.4
                   WHEN i.days_in_inventory < 4 THEN 0.8
                   ELSE 1
              END) AS evaluation_rate
      FROM (SELECT params.query_date, i.*,
                   TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, i.last_inbound_date, params.query_date) AS days_in_inventory
            FROM inventory i CROSS JOIN
                 (SELECT DATE('2020-02-04') as query_date UNION ALL
                  SELECT DATE('2020-02-05') as query_date UNION ALL
                  SELECT DATE('2020-02-06') as query_date
                 ) params
            WHERE timestamp_inventory = @query_date 
           ) i
     ) i;
```